# Jquery onclick, but do action after page reload

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I use Twitter/Bootstrap navbar and i want to add the class "active" dynamically.

There is a Jquery code which is supposed to do that: 
My problem: It adds the class "active" but it's also a link so the pages is going to be reloaded and the code loses its effectivness.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".nav li").click(function() {
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });
});
```

There are 5 elements. The click is working and it adds the class but the link in the LI is not working any more besides that it should remove the class active and should add it to the new one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your LI has a link in it try this

NOTE: If you DO reload, you will need a cookie or set the hash to remember the state of the active link

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/STfz7/)

```
$(function() {
    $(".nav li").click(function(e) {
      if (e.target.nodeName == "A") {
          e.preventDefault();
      }
      $(this).siblings().removeClass()
      $(this).addClass("active");
  });
});
```

With cookie functionality:

```
$(function() {
    $(".nav li").on("click",function(e) {
      if (e.target.nodeName == "A") {
          e.preventDefault();
      }
      $(this).siblings().removeClass()
      $(this).addClass("active");
      $.cookie("li",this.id);
  });
  var li = $.cookie("li");
  if (li) $("#"+li).addClass("active");
});
```

Comment: this kinda works but after the page reload it's the same again and none of them are "active".

Comment: I got a cookie therefore i can't understand why it's still not working

Comment: I started firebug -> cookies -> there is a cookie from my current session, I'm using rails if it matters did i understand it correct what you wanted ?

Comment: It's still not working after the reload it's the same ... thanks for you effort

Comment: Now imagine after you press one link it gets to another page after that the class "active" is gone again.

Comment: What other page? If you put the UL on every page it will work. Also if the URL changes you do not even NEED cookies. Please tell the whole story in your questions. I do not understand how one can go to another page and keep the nav. If you do, add the active to the link that matches the page you are on and remove all scripts

Comment: Alright it's basically a navigation bar at the top with "ladingpage", "about", "help" made with twitter/bootstrap ... there is a class called "active". When an element got the class attribute "active" it's going to be highlighted, Now your examples is working perfectly but it's also a link so we got another page and there we lose the settings after the page has loaded.

Comment: Where is the nav on the new page? If it has the same navigation and cookie code and is on the same path then the code would work. Do you have a URL

Comment: There is a template file which gets included, that file makees the header at every single page in the whole project. I can guarantee that the navbar is available on every page in the whole project.  It doesn't matter where you are located at the site you always got a navbar

Comment: I cannot help you further without seeing the output and console log

Comment: It's ok I'll take your example as the scaffold for my future work therefore i'll accept your answer because your example is some kind of prototype for the incoming code

Answer (score 2):

**DO NOT USE COOKIES.** Your page is reloading!

Instead of using a cookie to remember which link you clicked, you should just check if the links in the nav are the same as the current url, and if they're the same then add an active class.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".nav li").each(function(){
    var href = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
    if (href === window.location.pathname) {
      $(this).addClass('active');
    }
  });
});
```

this will run after your page reloads but it will be fine!

the problem with cookies is that someone will click a link, then go away and come back but your cookies will show them the incorrectly active link(**because the cookie stored it!!!**)

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
$("body").on("click",".nav li",function(){
        $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

this function will load after all the elements loaded